# Partition Problem

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

So I installed Trusty tahr alongside Xp yesterday because I got bored of the stupid green hill , it works like a charm

BUT

There's only one 6gb partition for the OS and I can't even resize it should I just remove XP? Or what should I do to make it larger?

Comment: post the screenshot of your gparted partition editor.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/7WLHs1L)

Comment: Oh , so it's basically from the live CD mode thingy huh okay then thanks!

Comment: Your HD is very small and most of the space is used by Windows. I would reinstall Ubuntu and use the whole HD. This will **destroy all your data** so make sure you've a backup. Also you'll lose Windows.

Comment: @Louis Matthijssen well i thought of that too but currently am super busy and can't do anything Big yet , Thanks in advance

Comment: boot from ubuntu live disk, resize your 48 GB ntfs partition then add the created unallocated space with your Ubuntu partition(`/dev/sda7`)

Answer (score 0):

and welcome.

Caution when delete partitions that you don't really know what is. It could be:

- Recovery partition also called "PQSERVICE" (specially on notebooks with pre-installed Windows)
- Linux Swap created after you installed Ubuntu
- Random data partition for documents

How do i check this information?

1.Press `Master Key or Windows Key on keyboard`

2.Search for `Disk` and click on Disk app

3.On device menu, should be your hard disk on the list, click on it

4.On graphical display, will show details of your partitions and what describes them

**Example of my HDD**

- PQService (windows recovery pre-installed)
- System Reserved (essential files to Bios and boot)
- Acer Partition 3 (windows7)
- Extended Parititon (Linux,Linux Swap and document partition)
- Free unallocated space (needed information to create partitions, system reserved)

If it is free space or windows partition that you don't want its safe to remove and expand your Linux in-use partition

[image: Example of my HDD]